# In Spree How to set status active/inactive for the product ..?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

When a product is created from the admin panel .it should be able to set the status for the product active/inactive . In the product listing page only the active product should be retrieved. any help on this please..?

**update**

I have added a field `status` in the spree product model. And also added one enum declaration as below :

```
enum status: { inactive: 1, active: 2 }
```

Here is the migration for the `status` field:

```
class AddStatusToSpreeProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :spree_products, :status, :integer, :default => 1
  end
end
```

After adding this the products listed for the status 2 and vice versa.

It works as expected .

Answer (score 4):

You can set a product to be inactive if it is not available as shown in this scope:

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.4.3/core/app/models/spree/product/scopes.rb#L190-L193

So, the simplest way to make a product inactive is to set its `available_on` to some point in the future.

Comment: If you have new logic which defines what it means to be available, you should update the scope which I linked above to include `.where(status: 2)`

Comment: @gmacdougall -- seems like a bad practice, and puts it on Merchandising to make sure those are managed correctly. On January 1st 2100 lots of products from 100-year old Spree stores will show up with lots of products! (JK). I am still planning on doing the discontinued_at change to the Spree core when I get a chance.